# How to make web parts appear on multiple pages?

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to duplicate a web part across multiple pages without having to recreate the web part? Preferably this would function in a way that an 'include' file functions on a PHP page, where only one file needs to be modified for that particular web part to be updated across all of the pages in which it is included.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the type of web part and the type of changes that would need to be made.  The web part properties are set on the given page it is used.  It is possible to export a web part which will retain its properties, but you are still essentially only doing a save as type function.

If you are working with content in side something like a content editor web part, it is possible to store the content centrally in a document library, and then reference it from multiple places within the site collection.  I've done this extensively with simple web parts and client side scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can include web parts in master pages or page layouts.  All pages using that master or page layout will then display the web part and to change it you only have to edit the original master or page layout.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I'll give it a go tomorrow and get back to you with thumbs up.

Comment: While it will put it on the page, I'm pretty sure web part properties would still be unique to the page.

Comment: @Mike - if you place it directly in the page then you cannot change the settings for the specific page.  However, if you add it to a web part zone then it acts like any other web part so could be customised per page.